# MacBook Pro display looks washed out in Windows (Boot Camp)

Tags: macbook-pro, bootcamp, windows, color

I have an early 2011 MacBook Pro and the display looks great under OS X, but is really washed out in Windows 7. I have installed all the drivers supplied by Apple and ran all the updates, but that didn't change anything. I think it's related to the color calibration, since Windows reports it's using "sRGB IEC61966-2.1" which was created in 1998. Yeah.

I tried importing the one from OS X for my display, but that just turned everything a dull brown. I also tried Windows 7's own display calibration wizard, but that just ended up looking horrible. What can I do to get decent looking text and pictures in Windows on this thing?

Answer (score 1):

Well, whenever I have a customer with this concern – and they are rare – I normally set the gamma profile to 2.2-ish, then grab the .icc profile for Windows, install it, no more problems. Basically not much different from your attempts...but sadly the only recommendation I could provide.

Answer (score 0):

The calibration wizard in OS X is better than the one in Windows but the ICC profile output from the OS X calibrator can be used in Windows. [See reference on superuser](https://superuser.com/questions/39731/calibrating-displays-in-boot-camp-3-0-on-macbook-with-external-display).

Comment: Unfortunately the trick of reusing OSX ICC profile on Windows doesn't work, at leat on an iMac 5k, although ICC profiles are supposed to be platform independant.
I tried this and the OSX profile is obviously misinterpreted under Windows as the colors are much darker (grey shifts to black, light blue to dark blue, etc.).
And if I try other OSX ICC profiles under Windows, I can't see any change in colors (while I can under OSX).
What a shame, because as iMacs are factory calibrated, I had supposed I could get the best of that screen under Windows too (without the need of calibrating it independe

Answer (score 0):

Well
You can go to this folder in your mac partition

> D:\Library\ColorSync\Profiles\Displays

And you will see a icc profile that OS X use to produce color in it's system.

File Name like

> Color LCD-E2D0B55C-862D-4B0E-BA07-E1BD2579493F

Then Double click to install icc profile to windows.

Next when you finished install icc profile from mac you NEED to apply to Windows system too.

Go to program name

> Color Management

**You can find this program by use windows search in start menu(If you're on Windows 7)
Or you can type the name of program on Start Screen (If you're on Windows 8)
Open it.

Then click Advanced tab and then click The "Change system defaults..."
(Another windows will appear now)

Click "Add..." 
Then Select you ICC Profile that recently installed before. And click OK

Go to Advanced tab again in the same window and change 
Device profile to your ICC Profile. (For me it named Display)

Then, Look at the Display Calibration. You might see checkbox name

> Use Windows display calibration

Click it two times. Now you will definitely see your display use the new ICC Profile now.

Close them all of that. And now it's ready to use !